# Execute GCP Cloud Run job with environment variable override using Python client

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud, google-cloud-run

I am trying to trigger a GCP Cloud Run job from a python script following the run_job documentation (https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/run/latest/google.cloud.run_v2.services.jobs.JobsClient#google_cloud_run_v2_services_jobs_JobsClient_run_job). However, I'm getting errors that I haven't been able to debug.

This is a job that already exists, but I need to overwrite an environment variable.

Here's is my code:

```
env_vars = [
        run_v2.EnvVar(name="VAR_1", value="var_1_value"),
        run_v2.EnvVar(name="VAR_2", value="var_2_value"),
    ]

# Set the env vars as container overrides
container_overrides = run_v2.RunJobRequest.Overrides.ContainerOverride(
        name="myjobname",
        env=env_vars
    )

request_override = run_v2.RunJobRequest.Overrides(
        container_overrides=container_overrides
)

# Initialize the request
job_name = f"projects/myproject/locations/mylocation/jobs/myjob"
request = run_v2.RunJobRequest(
        name=job_name,
        overrides=request_override
)

# Make the request
operation = client.run_job(request=request)
logging.info("Waiting for operation to complete...")

response = operation.result()
logging.info(f"Operation result: {response}")
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/decorators/base.py", line 220, in execute
    return_value = super().execute(context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 181, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 198, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/etl.py", line 128, in run_acolite
    request = run_v2.RunJobRequest(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/proto/message.py", line 604, in __init__
    super().__setattr__("_pb", self._meta.pb(**params))
TypeError: Message must be initialized with a dict: google.cloud.run.v2.RunJobRequest
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you installed the correct dependencies? Are you sure you not have conflict with other dag on your Airflow instance?

Comment: I had a similar issue recently. Just to comment: Comparing to other cloud providers, GCP documentation is really bad, lacking details, examples, and tips. And their SDK interface is often counter intuitive. Try multi-cloud, like with AWS or Azure, if possible, and you will know. Not answering your question but a more general suggestion based on my personal experience.

Comment: @Z.Wei - I have worked with Alibaba, AWS, Azure, IBM, Oracle, and GCP since their beginning. Each vendor has excellent services, documentation, and SDKs. None are perfect but finding what you need is easy. Since each vendor publishes the source code for their SDKs, they have provided the best documentation of all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We recently started using the [Cloud Run Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs?skip_cache=true) service in my workplace and I found myself needing to carry out the same task.

A dictionary with the Override Specification is required. I've amended the *Initialize request* block as per your example.

```py
override_spec = {
    'container_overrides': [
        {
            'env': [
                {'name': 'VAR_1', 'value': 'var_1_value'}
            ]
        }
    ]
}

# Initialize the request
job_name = f"projects/myproject/locations/mylocation/jobs/myjob"
request = run_v2.RunJobRequest(
        name=job_name,
        overrides=override_spec
)
```

Ref:
https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/run/latest/google.cloud.run_v2.types.RunJobRequest.Overrides